TimePicker throws java.lang.NullPointerException when tapping button to change value
Like the title states, I get the below exception when trying to change the value of the TimePicker via tapping the '+' or '-' button. Started getting this a after a few clients started to complained to me. Was only able to replicate it once I updated to the very latest version of Android from my Pixel 8 Pro (Build # AP1A.240305.019.A1, Android Version 14, Android Security Update 3/5/2024). Did not experience this with a build immediately before this one.
I commented out every piece of code. Just simply adding a TimePicker to the layout and tapping the button replicates the issues (no need to get a handle, modify or attach to handlers).
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.police.nycmoneymanagement, PID: 32232                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.EditText.hasFocus()' on a null object reference                                                                                                      at android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.updateInputState(TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.java:480)                                                                                                        at android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.-$$Nest$mupdateInputState(Unknown Source:0)                                                                                                     at android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate$2.onValueChange(TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.java:119)                                                                                                     at android.widget.NumberPicker.notifyChange(NumberPicker.java:2080)                                                                                                     at android.widget.NumberPicker.setValueInternal(NumberPicker.java:1850)                                                                                                     at android.widget.NumberPicker.changeValueByOne(NumberPicker.java:1879)                                                                                                     at android.widget.NumberPicker.-$$Nest$mchangeValueByOne(Unknown Source:0)                                                                                                      at android.widget.NumberPicker$1.onClick(NumberPicker.java:723)                                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7729)                                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7706)                                                                                                       at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30484)                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)

Probably your EditText is empty when you are accessing it.
Provide the code part where you are getting this exception to get a solution. Without code no one can help you.

I do not access it. There is no code. Simply having the TimePicker in the xml layout file and tapping the + or - buttons creates the issue. I do not even have an 'id' attribute in the xml file.

I do not access it. There is no code!!
What do you mean? Are you using any third-party library?

No. Just creating a useless widget with no "code-behind" and change the value by hitting the '+' or '-' buttons replicates the issue. It is only when you update to the most recent patch/update. I have a pixel 8 pro which was just 2 months behind in updates and it works fine. When I update to the version indicated in the post, that is when the issue manifests.

I have just encountered the same issue on a Pixel 6 with Android 14 build AP1A.240405.002
Security patch 5th April 2024
It's reproducible with a TimePickerDialog which uses a custom theme such as:
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.my_time_picker_dialog_theme, this, startHr, startMin, true);
<style name="my_time_picker_dialog_theme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff000000</item>    <!--header background-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#ff000000</item>   <!--calendar background-->

But the crash doesn't occur when using a standard theme such as:
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK, this, startHr, startMin, true);
// options: THEME_TRADITIONAL THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK THEME_HOLO_LIGHT THEME_HOLO_DARK
(Just to rule out a couple of recent library updates:
01-05-24 Updated implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0' from 18.1.0
01-05-24 Updated implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.1' from 1.2.0
I reverted them, but the crash remains, so it's nothing to do with those)

Note: My TimePickerDialog was called using the constructor without the themeResId parameter, and the error occurs.
